# ADC value changes with changing power supply

Tags: adc, load-cell

I'm measuring weight using hx711 ADC and load cell. 
HX711  schmatic: [image]

I use 12V 1A power supply and 6V/4Ah dry cell. Also I use MT3608 boost converter to increase battery voltage to 12V because battery voltage is not enough for voltage regulator (LM2576). LM2575 need at least 8 volt. 
MT3608 boost converter schematic: [image]

There is also a charger in the system for dry cell.

charger schematic: [image]

When I disconnect the power supply, the ADC value drifts. It causes a 100 gram offset. Both power supply gives 12 volt but ADC values are changed if I start to use battery. What can be the reason? I'm sorry if this information is not enough.

Comment: HX711 has internal voltage regulation and voltage reference so a change in supply voltage should not change the readings. This hints of an electromagnetic interference problem, which means you'll also have to post pictures of your setup.

Comment: @peufeu Thank you for your answer. I added schematics. Is the pcb layout necessary to see if the problem is caused by electromagnetic interference.

Comment: Hmm it's probably something linked to the earth ground ?